# Expander button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF, C#, and XAML (come from obj-c) I am just trying to figure out how to get it to where the expander control's button is hidden, and appears on mouse over? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this you will have to customize expander control with the help of ControlTemplate. You can have an image in the control template for the toggle button whose source will not be anything by default. On mouse over, path to an image can be given and the image will be visible.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ExpanderToggleButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Border x:Name="ExpanderToggleButtonBorder" Height="30">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Name="img" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Image>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContent" Grid.Column="0" Margin="50,0,0,0"
                              ContentSource="Content" >
                </ContentPresenter>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                             Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Source"
                                Value="path of whichever image is required"
                                TargetName="img"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ExpanderTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <DockPanel>
            <ToggleButton DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                          Template="{StaticResource ExpanderToggleButtonTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" OverridesDefaultStyle="True">
            </ToggleButton>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpanderContent" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="ExpanderContent" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>

        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Is this the only way? Would I be able to set
<Expander Visibility="Hidden"> and then set it to show in a mouseover event handler? I did that but this.isVisible or this.Show dont work. Like I said I am new to C#

Comment: @user3593696 what exactly do u need? the whole expander control should be hidden except for mouse over or the expander toggle button and/or header be hidden except for mouse over? because expander header contains toggle button as well as header text.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate a google news article container. It contains a link and short description, when you put your mouse over it a button appears in the top right corner of the container, and then when you click it the container expands and reveals a description. I am trying to replicate that in XAML/C#